# Ubuntu not showing up in bootloader menu

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning, dual-boot

I'm not too sure what to google to find an answer, so I came here.

My computer had Windows 7 on it, then I installed Ubuntu 13.04. Then I created a separate partition and installed Windows 7 on it again. Doing this brought my bios back from GRUB to the windows one, and on the menu it now shows two windows 7's, and not the Ubuntu. All partitions are still there. There are files on the Ubuntu partition that I would like to have back.

Can someone help me boot back into Ubuntu or introduce me to software that allows me to look at and transfer the files on the partition elsewhere? If it helps, I have a Dell XPS l502x.

Comment: Please read this answer, is not an exact duplicate, but it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [EasyBCD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml) to add a Grub2 option into the Windows boot screen. That would simplify booting into Ubuntu, as you can select the **Grub2** option when you 
(re)boot. Please note, EasyBCD will give you multiple Grub options to choose from. You want Grub2, not any other Grub option EasyBCD will offer.

If you don't mind using BOOTMGR (the Windows Vista/Seven/Eight boot screen) to select which OS you load, that's all you need to do.

However, if you prefer to start with Grub, you could mount the Windows partition into Ubuntu, run `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`, and finally `sudo update-grub`. You should probably replace the /dev/sda part of the command line with whatever drive Ubuntu is installed on. Please note that there is no number (1,2,3,4,5...) in `sda`. This is intentional, as (I believe) it's telling the system which **hard drive** to install Grub ontu, not the partition.

From there, you can reboot into Windows and remove the Grub2 option from the Windows screen, if you so desire.